# Generify class because of unchecked casting warning

Tags: java, generics, casting, warnings

I have the following class with methods marked as unchecked that give me a warning. They compile/work fine but I am interested if there is a way to generify the class as IntelliJ IDEA is offering me (but unable to do) to remove the warnings.

```
public abstract class Attribute {

private final AttributedNode containerNode;
private boolean computationComplete;

public Attribute(AttributedNode node) {
    this.containerNode = node;
    this.computationComplete = false;
}

public AttributedNode getContainerNode() {
    return containerNode;
}

public Attribute getAttributeFromChildNode(int childIndex, AttributeNameEnum attributeName) {
    AttributedNode node = getContainerNode().getChild(childIndex);
    return node.getAttribute(attributeName);
}

public String getChildNodeText(int index) {
    return getContainerNode().getChild(index).getText();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T, E extends Attribute> List<T> getListOfChildAttributeValues(AttributeNameEnum name) {
    List<T> result = new LinkedList<>();
    for (AttributedNode node : this.getContainerNode().getChildren()) {
        E attribute = (E) node.getAttribute(name);
        result.add((T) attribute.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}

public <T extends Attribute> Object getAttributeValueFromContainer(AttributeNameEnum name) {
    return this.<T>getAttributeValueFromNode(name, this.getContainerNode());
}

public <T extends Attribute> Object getAttributeValueFromParent(AttributeNameEnum name) {
    return this.<T>getAttributeValueFromNode(name, this.getContainerNode().getParent());
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Attribute> Object getAttributeValueFromNode(AttributeNameEnum name, AttributedNode node) {
    T attribute = (T) node.getAttribute(name);
    return attribute.getValue();
}
// other methods eluded
```

P.S. I apologize ahead of time of maybe my lack of understanding Generics.

Comment: Pretty tough to help without knowing what AttributeNameEnum and AttributeNode classes look like.

Comment: It is not permitted to cast to a generic type, like `(E)` or `(T)`.  You must pass a Class as an additional method parameter, like `Class<T> valueClass`, and you must cast using `valueClass.cast(…)`.

Comment: @VGR It is permitted, it's just usually a bad idea.

Comment: It's permitted by the compiler, yes.  I should have said "not safe" instead.